# How to do window placement without the numpad?

Tags: 11.04, gnome-classic

I have a computer without a numberpad, I would love to be able to do the window placement thing (example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>KP1</kbd>).  Is there a way I can reset the shortcuts for this?

Answer (score 1):

Install the [CompizConfig Settings Manager](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager).

Open CCSM and locate the "Grid" options under "Window Management". The first tab is bindings which has the key commands for window placement.